# Find the index list element in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm trying to list.index the first occurrence of a variable in a list element within a list of lists.
For example:

```
myList = [[[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10],[[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10] . . . ]
```

I would like to do something like:

```
index = myList.index((0,0))
myList[index] : [[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10]
```

So far, I am trying to achieve this with the following piece of code:

```
i = 0
for cage in myList:
    if cage[0][0] == A:
       print('Found')
       break
    i += 1
print(self.Cages[i])
```

But , I woud like to find a more pythonic solution to my problem.

Comment: You should use enumerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the best data structure? Can not you rethink your program so that it generates something more compellable? Such nested lists are either anti-pythonic...

Anyway, why I would recommand with your code as it is to use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#next) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
index = next(i for i, x in enumerate(myList) if x[0][0] == A)
```

Comment: My whole code is based on this data structure , so very few options now . Anyways , It worked for my like charm . I will checks about enumerate() ,too , for  future convience

Answer (score 0):

An option would be using `while` to loop over `iter(my_list)`:

```
my_list = [[[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10],[[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10]]

my_iterator = iter(my_list)

item = next(my_iterator)
while (0, 0) not in item[0]:
    item = next(my_iterator)

print item
```

**Output:**

```
>>> my_list = [[[(2,2),(1,1)],'add',10], [[(0,0),(1,1)],'add',10], [[(3,3),(1,1)],'add',10]]
>>>
>>> my_iterator = iter(my_list)
>>>
>>> item = next(my_iterator)
>>> while (0, 0) not in item[0]:
...     item = next(my_iterator)
...
>>> print item
[[(0, 0), (1, 1)], 'add', 10]
```